# pysnmp - how to use compiled mibs during agent implementation

Tags: mib, pysnmp

the snmp agent implementation examples provided in pysnmp don't really leverage the mib.py file generated by compiling a mib. Is it possible to use this file to simplify agent implementation?  Is such an example available, for a table.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, existing `mibdump.py` tool is primarily designed for manager-side MIB compilation. However compiled MIB is still useful or even  sometimes crucial for agent implementation.

For simple scalars you can mass-replace `MibScalar` classes with `MibScalarInstance` ones. And add an extra trailing `.0` to their OID. For example [this line](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.py#L27):

```
sysDescr = MibScalar((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), DisplayString().subtype(subtypeSpec=ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255))).setMaxAccess("readonly")
```

would change like this:

```
sysDescr = MibScalarInstance((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0), DisplayString().subtype(subtypeSpec=ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255))).setMaxAccess("readonly")
```

For SNMP tables it's way more tricker because there can be several cases. If it's a static table which never changes its size, then you can basically replace `MibTableColumn` with `MibScalarInstance` plus append the index part of the OID. For example [this line](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-MIB.py#L60):

```
sysORID = MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 9, 1, 2), ObjectIdentifier()).setMaxAccess("readonly")
```

would look like this (note index 12345):

```
sysORID = MibScalarInstance((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 9, 1, 2, 12345), ObjectIdentifier()).setMaxAccess("readonly")
```

The rest of `MibTable*` classes can be removed from the MIB.py.

For dynamic tables that change their shape either because SNMP agent or SNMP manager modify them, you might need to preserve all the `MibTable*` classes and extend/customize the [MibTableColumn](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/smi/mibs/SNMPv2-SMI.py#L825) class to make it actually managing your backend resources in response to SNMP calls.

A hopefully relevant [example](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/agent-side-mib-implementations.html#implementing-conceptual-table).